# How to set environment variables using python in Windows/Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x

There are different way needs to follow to set the environment variable.

In Windows,

```
import subprocess    
check_output("setx env_var env_value", shell=True)
```

In Linux,

```
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.bashrc"), "a") as f:
    f.write("export env_var=env_val")
```

Apart form this, Is there any common way to follow setting environment variable in Windows/Linux?

Comment: You can use `os.system("setx env_var env_value")`.

Comment: Let subprocess handle the quoting for you in case the value has spaces; there's no need to use `shell=True`; and no reason to care about the output from setx.exe, just the exit code: `subprocess.check_call(['setx.exe', 'env_var', 'env_value'])`.